# Regular Expression for matching content between bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx that select something like `[something` and not support `[something]` for first one I know this

```
/\[[\w]+/g
```

But for not selecting if content between `[]` I don't know what should I do.

Comment: This is an open-ended (no pun intended) question in the sense of how do you define an open bracket which never closes?  If you encounter `word]` several words later does it mean the first one should not be matched?

Comment: Have you tried using a regex playground like this: http://regexr.com/

Comment: `/\[\w+(?![\w\]])/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex can't necessarily solve your problem.

If you're always matching the entire string, you can ensure that the end of the string comes before any occurrence of the "]" character:

```js
var reg = /\[[^\]]+$/;

/*

  How is this regex working?

  - The first two characters, `"\["`, mean to match a literal "["
  - The next 5 characters, `"[^\]]"`, match ANY character except
    the "]" character. The outer "[]" define a character class,
    and when "^" appears as the first character of a character
    class it means to invert the character class, so only accept
    characters which DON'T match. Then the only character which
    cannot be matched is an escaped right-square-bracket: "\]"
  - Add one more character to the previous 5 - `"[^\]]+"` - and
    you will match any number (one or more) of characters which
    aren't the right-square-bracket.
  - Finally, match the `"$"` character, which means "end of input".
    This means that no "]" character can be matched before the input
    ends.

*/

[
    '[',
    '[aaa',
    'aa[bb',
    '[[[[',
    ']]]]',
    '[aaa]',
    '[aaa[]',
    '][aaa'
].forEach(function(val) {
    console.log('Match "' + val + '"? ' + (reg.test(val) ? 'Yes.' : 'No.'));
});
```